# add column and do a fill down

Tags: text-processing

I have this file `myfile.txt`:

```
firstdbname
seconddbname
thirddbname
.
.
lastdbname
```

I want to create a script to get an output like:

```
firstdbname       x     y
seconddbname      x     y
thirddbname       x     y
.                 .     .
.                 .     .
lastdbname        x     y
```

So basically I want to add 2 new columns with static values filled down until the end of the file.

Comment: to add the static values in first row of the file I did : paste myfile.txt <(echo "x") <(echo"y") -- delimiters '  ' but I am not sure how to do the fill down

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk -v OFS=' ' '{ print $0, "x", "y" }' infile >newfile
```

change `OFS=' '` value from space character to any string you would like to columns delimited with that.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to [αғsнιη's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/612555/116858), but using `sed` to add the new columns, and using tabs as delimiters:

```
sed $'s/$/\tx\ty/' file >newfile
```

This assumes that you're using a shell that understands `$'...'` as a "C string" and expands the `\t` sequences to literal tab characters.  The `sed` command will simply "replace the end of the line (`$`)" with a tab, the `x`, another tab, and the `y`.

The processed data is then redirected to a new file.

Comment: @AdminBee It does.